# how to print model query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am new in laravel and have to save the record in table , i am using this code to insert the value

```
$model->studentRollId = $value1;
$model->resident_permit_number = $value2;
$model->save()
```

i am not getting any error but record not inserting in the table , so can anyone please tell me how can i print the executed query by the $model->save(), i tried DB::getQueryLog() but its not shiwing the query log so i can fin what is the issue . thanks in advance

Comment: `DB::getQueryLog()` will only enable the logging to see the log you can do `\DB::getQueryLog()`

Comment: Here above the $model variable, where is it pointing the Model or DB::Table..?

Answer (score 2):

Use `->toSql()`, after your `$model->save()`, just do a `dd($model->toSql())`

Edit: Have you do a `\DB::enableQueryLog();`?

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$model->studentRollId = $value1;
$model->resident_permit_number = $value2;
$model->save()
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: hello thanks for the replay its not printing the insert query

Comment: yes i did try it but all above select query is printing but , insert query not printing .

Comment: how about the `enableQueryLog()` before you new up your model?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$model->studentRollId = $value1;
$model->resident_permit_number = $value2;
$data = $model->toSql();
dd($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have studentRollId and resident_permit_number in the $fillable array?

Go to the $model and check if you have something like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'studentRollId',
    'resident_permit_number'
];
```

Another solution would be to insert data in raw like this:

```
    DB::table('table_name')->insert([
        'studentRollId' => $value1,
        'resident_permit_number' => $value2
    ]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned the column names in $fillable in you model. In laravel to insert a data in table you have to mentioned the columns names in $fillable method.

e.g.
Suppose you have users table and for that table you have User model.

In User.php add following method

```
protected $fillable = [
        'list of columns'
    ];
```